# Passing an array from txt file to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a simple function of the form:

```
double f(double x)
{
...
}
```

For that function, I want to use data from a txt file, which I pass to an array:

```
ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("data.txt");


    //Counting lines
    string s;
    int nlines=0;

    while(!inFile.eof()){
        getline(inFile, s);
        nlines++;
    }

    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    while(!inFile.eof()){
        inFile >> a[entry_data];
        inFile >> b[entry_data++]; 
    }

    inFile.close();
```

If I put this code inside the function `f`, each time the function is called, it will have to open the file, create the array... and so on. I want to avoid this by defining the array just the first time the function is called, or before. How can I do this?

I know that if I define the array in the main scope and pass it to the function as an argument I can solve this, but I want to keep the main scope as clean as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your function in a class, and use a singleton there to get the data you want.

Comment: OT but a bug: `while(!inFile.eof()){` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Why are you counting the lines?! Total waste of electrons.

Comment: My guess is the OP can't use std::vector. That is not at all clear since the line count is not used and we don't know where `a` and `b` are declared or allocated.

Comment: @drescherjm cannot use vector but can use seekg? Found an idiot professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create an instance that will read your data.

```
class DataHolder
{
    DataHolder()
    {
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("data.txt");

    double v1, v2;

    while(inFile >> v1 >> v2){
        a.push_back(v1); 
        b.push_back(v2);
    }
    }
public:
    static DataHolder& getInstance()
    {
        static DataHolder d;
        return d;
    }
    std::vector<double> a, b;
};
```

Then in your function, use the data holder:

```
double f(double x)
{
    auto& d = DataHolder::getInstance();
    // use the holders data
}
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I have been testing your idea, but I can't get it to work. I have tried different variations based on the same idea, but using literally what you have posted I get `error: 'DataHolder' does not refer to a value
    auto& d = DataHolder.getInstance();`

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's ::

Answer (score 0):

Your `f` function takes 1 (one) value, not an array.

You want to use `std::vector<double>` instead of array, if you want to pass the data.

Your loop should be:

```
double value1, value2;
std::vector<double> a;
std::vector<double> b;
while (inFile >> value1 >> value2)
{
   a.push_back(value1);
   b.push_back(value2);
}
```

You can use your `f` function:

```
const size_t size = a.size();
for (size_t index = 0; index < size; ++size)
{
  double result = f(a[index]);
  //...
}
```

**Edit 1: Function to Load**
You could create an input function and call it once in `main`:

```
void input_data(std::istream& input, std::vector<double>& a, std::vector<double>& b)
{
  double value1, value2;
  while (input >> value1 >> value2)
  {
     a.push_back(value1);
     b.push_back(value2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants. `a` and `b` are read inside `f`, not outside.

Comment: Basically the function uses a bunch of parameters that are in a file, and OP doesn't want to load them each time the function is called.

Comment: This gives the OP some tools to work with.  I don't like giving 100% solutions, I like to make the posters think.

Comment: Also, there is a design smell that the OP should be using a `class` that models the record, instead of using parallel containers.